# {{#item.0}} checks appearing on the stack

Tags: mustache

This seems to be by design as per the wording of the [mustache documentation](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Partials), and (at least) the perl and JS implementations, but still a gotcha...

We make extensive use of `{{#items.0}}` type checks to see if an array has any items before rendering the container and the items themselves (`{{#items}}{{value1}}{{value2}}{{/items}}`).
This gives example code like:

```
{{#items.0}}
  <p>found items</p>
  {{#items}}
    {{#first}}
      <li><strong>{{name}}</strong></li>
    {{/first}}
    {{#link}}
      <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
    {{/link}}
  {{/items}}
{{/items.0}}
{{^items.0}}
  <p>no items</p>
{{/items.0}}
```

The issue here is that the 0th item is now part of the context stack, meaning that if items 1+ do not have a specific named value, but the 0th does, that value will be rendered instead.
If you put the above mustache into the [demo](https://mustache.github.io/#demo), you get this broken output:

```
<p>found items</p>
<li><strong>red</strong></li>
<li><strong>green</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Green">green</a></li>
<li><strong>blue</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Blue">blue</a></li>
```

It now thinks every item is "first" as it pulls that value from the `{{#items.0}}` context.

We can work around it in some cases, by changing `{{subitem.value}}` (which also exists at `.0`) to `{{#subitem}}{{value}}{{/subitem}}`.
This works, as the `.n` entries *will* have a `subitem` which becomes the new context, and then looks for `value` which `.0` (and `.n`) doesn't.

Is anyone aware of a way of doing that check without putting it in the context stack?